# Azure Dev Ops - How to require 2 of 3 approvers on pre-deployment approvals?

Tags: azure-devops, devops

I have a pre-deployment approval on Azure Dev Ops where I need the approval of two out of three approvers to proceed to the next stage.

However, at the moment the interface makes it look like you can either have all of the three approving or just one of them approving. I wouldn't like to have the three of them approving it because there is always the chance that someone might not be on the office.

Answer (score 0):

> Azure Dev Ops - How to require 2 of 3 approvers on pre-deployment approvals?

Indeed, there is really no such option **Minimum number of reviewers** of branch Policies for pre-deployment approvals at this moment:

[image]

If it is important to you, you can open a new ticket [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21):

[image]

Besides, what I can think of is that the **workaround** is divide the three approvers into three groups (`AB`, `AC`, `BC`), then add the three groups to the Approvers option and select any one user on Approval order option. Of course, when you have many approvers, it can be very troublesome.

Hope this helps.